# Google Scripts Runtime Optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I'm working with google scripts for the first time after a lot of work in VBA. When running the code I get a message that the script is taking too long to run. Certain parts such as .getValue() and .setValue() are causing the issues, but I'm not sure how to re-write the code to better optimize. 
Here is the Code:

```
function getPredictions() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Carter = ss.getSheetByName("Carter");
  var back = ss.getSheetByName("Back");
  var monthsLeft= Carter.getRange(13,15)
  var months = monthsLeft.getValue();
  var total = 0;
  Carter.getRange("d2").setValue(months);
  for(var i = 13;Carter.getLastRow(); i++){
    if(Carter.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != ""){
      total = 0;
      var k = 17;
      monthsLeft = Carter.getRange(i,15).getValue();
      for(var j = 2; j<29; j++){
        if(back.getRange(j, 2).getValue() <= monthsLeft){
          total = total + back.getRange(j, 3).getValue();
          Carter.getRange(i,k).setValue((back.getRange(j, 3).getValue() / Carter.getRange(i,16).getValue()) * Carter.getRange(i,11).getValue());
          k++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function getMonthsL () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Carter = ss.getSheetByName("Carter");
  for(var i = 13; i < Carter.getLastRow(); i++){
     if(Carter.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != ""){
       Carter.getRange(i,15).setFormula('=if(day($B$5)>20,DATEDIF($B$5,I' +i + ',"M"),DATEDIF($B$5,I' +i+',"M")+1)');
     }
   }
}

function getMonthP(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Carter = ss.getSheetByName("Carter");
  var back = ss.getSheetByName("Back");
  var total = 0;
  for(var i = 13; i < Carter.getLastRow(); i++){
    total = 0;
    if(Carter.getRange(i, 2).getValue() != ""){
      for(var j = 2; Carter.getRange(i,15).getValue() >= back.getRange(j,2).getValue(); j++){
        total = total + back.getRange(j,3).getValue(); 
      }
    Carter.getRange(i,16).setValue(total);
    }
  }
}

function runAll(){
getMonthsL();
getMonthP();
getPredictions();
}
```

Any help/ explanation on the best way to refactor this would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of getting individual cell values - use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) to get the data in natural grids and access the values using [array indexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Multi-dimensional_arrays). Also some [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect this answer to be correct but I thought I'd just give you an example of what many of us  would recommend to you.  Trying to limit the use of getValue() and try to use getValues which returns a two dimensional array (sort of).

One of the complexities is that indexes start at zero and rows and columns start at one.  So it can be a bit challenging at times to keep everything straight but once you do, you'll find that the code can run 10 times faster.

```
function getPredictions() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Carter=ss.getSheetByName("Carter");
  var crg=Carter.getDataRange();
  var carterA=crg.getValues();
  var back=ss.getSheetByName("Back");
  var backA=back.getDataRange().getValues();
  var months=carterA[12][14];
  var total=0;
  carterA[3][1]=months;
  for(var i = 12;i<carterA.length; i++)
  {
    if(carterA[i][1]!= "")
    {
      total = 0;
      var k = 16;
      var monthsLeft = carterA[i][14];
      for(var j=0;j<28;j++)//I probably got this indexing incorrect
      {
        if(backA[j][1] <= monthsLeft)
        {
          total = total + backA[j][2];
          carterA[i][k]=backA[j][2];
          k++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  crg.setValues(carterA);//This save all the changes
  //Didn't do backA because I don't think you changed it.
}
```

I'm pretty sure this won't work.  But hopefully it will give you an idea of how you can make the code faster.